# Javascript button pressed fade parent class out only one time works

Tags: javascript

Hello so I did that when I click on 'decline' button it would fade out that 'td' and it works but it works only for the first one, I mean if there is more `<td>` which contains more 'decline' buttons it won't work ONLY WORKS ON FIRST BUTTON

code:
JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () {
    $("#declinebutton").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('td').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Username
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="declinebutton" id="declinebutton">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Decline request
        </button>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It works as it should. IDs are unique, you should use class selector instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **Just**  to change `declinebutton` from and **id** to a **class** attribute and change the reference to it as well in you JS code, here is an example :

```
$(function () {
    $(".declinebutton").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('td').fadeOut();
    });
});



<tr>
    <td>
        Username
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger declinebutton" name="declinebutton">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Decline request
        </button>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Note:**
**IDs** should be **unique**, meaning one ID identify one and only one element whereas **CLASS** can identify more than one element.

So if you want to target a list of elements just give them the same class name and you are ready to go, hope this helps.

Comment: In your example, the button element has two `class` attributes :)